# How to bind d3 generated HTML elements to scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am generating nodes in d3 in an angular directive, and I would like the classes of the nodes to be bound dynamically to an element in my scope. Below is a general outline of what I would like to do:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){
            var node = d3.selectAll('.node')
                         .data(nodes)
                         .enter().append('circle')
                         .classed('selected',function(d){return d.id=scope.selected.id})
        }
    }
})
```

This is pseudocode, but essentially d3 is generating these nodes/circles, and I want the class of these circles to depend on the value of an element within the scope. So, if at any point in time I modify the scope.selected.id, it should affect the node's class. Using the approach shown above, however, does not work. I have tried modifying the scope.selected.id, but the classes of the nodes are unaffected.

How can I dynamically bind a d3 generated element to scope? I don't want to redraw nodes whenever the scope is modified. I simply want their classes to be binded to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Add a watch around scope.selected in your link function then wrap your d3 drawing code in a function and call that method when the watch fires.

(BTW a fiddle is always easier to deal with when asking questions)

You might want to read up on the General update pattern for D3 too http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

It will both make life easier and your updates faster if you get to grips with the various stages a D3 documents lifecycle has.

```
    function update(data) {

      // DATA JOIN
      // Join new data with old elements, if any.
      var text = svg.selectAll("text")
          .data(data);

      // UPDATE
      // Update old elements as needed.
      text.attr("class", "update");

      // ENTER
      // Create new elements as needed.
      text.enter().append("text")
          .attr("class", "enter")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * 32; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em");

      // ENTER + UPDATE
      // Appending to the enter selection expands the update selection to include
      // entering elements; so, operations on the update selection after appending to
      // the enter selection will apply to both entering and updating nodes.
      text.text(function(d) { return d; });

      // EXIT
      // Remove old elements as needed.
      text.exit().remove();
    }
```